# XNA Phone 7: game locks up, no exception, but still 'running'

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7, xna

This is a weird one. The game does not exit, does not throw an exception as far as I can tell, but totally locks up (perhaps freezes is a better word). If there's a way to trouble shoot this in VS I apparently don't know what it is.

I'm looking far a general strategy: is there some tool in VS2010 where I can monitor this? Get some kind of output? Or perhaps a strategic spot to place a try/catch in the phone 7 game code?

I'm pretty much stuck, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you not pause the game, in VS2010, and step through the code to see where it is freezing?

Comment: Your the second person to mention a pause game feature. This must be on a menu somewhere and I haven't noticed it yet.

Comment: On the standard toolber there are 3 icons that look like a _play_, _pause_ and _stop_ button. If you press the pause button it will break at the current executing piece of code. You can then step through the code. This is debugging 101 and not XNA specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the debugger attached on the emulator or device and the lock up happens hit the pause button and see if there is a call stack.

Comment: All I've ever done is web programming on VS and had stopped wondering why I'd ever use the pause button. In fact, completely forgot about it's existence. I popped it open and what do you know... unsatisfied loop condition. Thanks for the wake up call.

Comment: Yeah most of the time it just breaks into the "waiting for something to happen loop" that is typically in some system code. Every once in a awhile it comes in handy though.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the beta of the Mango tools and then run the app through the (new, built in) profiler.

If you forcibly terminate the app once frozen you should be able to look at the profiler data to see what happens when it "locks up".